# add Cell value in Excel in Debug mode (VBA)

Tags: vba

Is it not possible to add to watch in Excel 2010 Debug mode something like: Cells(1,2).Value in order to see when exactly the cell value is altered during subroutine processing?
Many thanks in advance!

Comment: Yes We Can! Yes We Can!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debug-> add watch and write inside something like

```
ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Cells(1,1).Value
```

or you can write

```
debug.print Thisworkbook.sheets(1).cells(1,1).value
```

and in immediate you will see printed values.

Hope I understood your question :)